# AngularJS - accessing toState information in my .run() function for authorization

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building a basic CRUD app in Angular and Rails and having trouble restricting a logged in user from accessing the "edit" state for another user's information. I am using Devise and angular-devise, which provides an Auth service including `Auth.isAuthenticated()` and `Auth._currentUser`. Here is part of my `app.js` file to show what I've got going on that works:

```
// the rest of my .config file consisting of lots of states...

.state('home.editThing', {
  url:'things/:id/edit',
  controller: 'ThingController as ctrl',
  authenticate: true,
  authorize: true,
  templateUrl: 'app/views/thing.html',
  resolve: {
    thing: ["$stateParams", "DataService", function ($stateParams, DataService) {
      return DataService.getThing($stateParams.id);
    }]
  }
})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('welcome');
}])

.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'Auth', function($rootScope, $state, Auth){
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){
  if ( toState.authenticate && !Auth.isAuthenticated()){
    alert('Log in to create and edit things');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
 });
}]);
```

This properly restricts a user who isn't logged in from accessing the edit state. I would also like to allow users to edit only their own things, and have tried unsuccessfully to add authorization to my .run function and edit state. In the code above I've already added an authorization attribute to the state object. I'd like to add a second conditional to my .run function, something like:

```
if (toState.authorize && thing.user.id != Auth._currentUser.id) { alert('You don't have permission to edit this thing')};
```

However I can't access `thing.user.id` in my .run function. I am unable to access the data in the toState's resolve object. I also tried injecting my DataService into the .run function to retrieve the information that way but can't get that to work either.

Comment: `thing` is only available in controller. Can use a `then()` in the resolve to do a redirect if needed

Comment: Unsure how this would work. Put a .then(function(result){ redirect logic }); inside my resolve.thing object? Tried that but unable to access variables to perform the result.data.user.id == Auth._currentUser.id logic inside of it.